# Author value does not display when not provided

Tags: java

I am trying to create a java program where I have a superclass ReadingMaterial and many different sub classes namely Newspaper, Manga, Novel and TextBook. Now, Readingmaterial has 3 data members and each of the other classes have 2 different data members each.

I am trying to display the String that I am creating like  for example:

```
allMat.add(new Newspaper("NewYork_Times"));
```

I want the  "NewYork_Times" and the date, the author to be displayed
can  anyone tell me what I am doing  wrongly?

ps: I am new in JAVA programming

Newspaper class

```
public class Newspaper
        extends ReadingMaterial {

    private String title = "BHCC_Newspaper";

    //public Newspaper(){}
    public Newspaper(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Newspaper(String title, String author, boolean readingMaterial) {
        super(author, readingMaterial);
        this.title = title;
    }

    //getter
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    // setter
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void displayReadingMaterials() {
        System.out.println(getTitle() + "\n Microsoft recruited 15 students from a community college.\n");
    }
}
```

this is the superclass

```
public class ReadingMaterial implements Comparable {

    private String author = "Lydie";
    private boolean readingMaterial;
    private java.util.Date dateCreated;

    // no-arg constructor
    public ReadingMaterial() {
        dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    }
    // arg constructor

    public ReadingMaterial(String author, boolean readingMaterial) {
        dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
        this.author = author;
        this.readingMaterial = readingMaterial;
    }
    // getters

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public java.util.Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public boolean getReadingMaterial() {
        return readingMaterial;
    }
    // setters

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public void setReadingMaterial(boolean readingMaterial) {
        this.readingMaterial = readingMaterial;
    }

    public void displayReadingMaterials() {
        System.out.println("Written on " + getDateCreated() + " by " + getAuthor()
                + " on all ReadingMaterial: " + getReadingMaterial());
    }

//Comparator for sorting the list
     public static  Comparator <ReadingMaterial> testCompare = new Comparator <ReadingMaterial>(){

             public int compare(ReadingMaterial readMat1, ReadingMaterial readMat2){


             return (int) (readMat1.getAuthor().compareTo(readMat2.getAuthor()));
             }
     };
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Written on " + dateCreated + " by " + author
                + " on all ReadingMaterial: " + readingMaterial;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object t) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }



}
```

and this is the main

```
package readingmaterial;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Collections;


public class ReadingFactory {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create and initialize a newspaper, a manga, a textbook and a novel

        List<ReadingMaterial> allMat = new ArrayList<ReadingMaterial>();
        allMat.add(new Newspaper("NewYork_Times"));
        allMat.add(new Manga("Naruto"));
        allMat.add(new TextBook("Bible"));
        allMat.add(new Novel("Argonauts"));
        //Iterator<ReadingMaterial> readMat = all.iterator();

        System.out.println("ArrayList elements after sorting in ascending order : ");

       Collections.sort(allMat, ReadingMaterial.testCompare);

       for(ReadingMaterial str: allMat){
            System.out.println(str);

        //ReadingMaterial[] allMat={newspaper,manga,textbook,novel};
        //for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
          //   allMat[i].displayReadingMaterials();
        // }
    }
    // this method show the polymorphic call and display any reading material

}
```

Comment: The cast in `(int) (readMat1.getAuthor().compareTo(readMat2.getAuthor()));` is redundant. The code as shown has unbalanced curly braces and won't compile.

Comment: This question is asking why no author is displayed when no author is provided.

Comment: By the way, the troublesome `Date` class has been supplanted by the java.time classes such as `java.time.Instant`.

Comment: thank you very much, I fixed my code and it's now working

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you are doing `new Newspaper("NewYork_Times")` you are using the default super constructor, with no args, which means `author` is not set.
therefore, you are getting null pointer on your comparator (`getAuthor` returns null):

```
readMat1.getAuthor().compareTo(readMat2.getAuthor())
```

You should:
1. add null check to your comparator
2. if you count on author for comparing, you can't allow it to be null. either don't have constructor without it, or set a default value (like you do with the date)